# Wildfly 8.2: importing wildcard certificate, intermediate certificate missing

Tags: java, ssl, wildfly-8, spring-saml

I've followed [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/237517) for importing my GeoTrust Wildcard certificate for my company domain. From GeoTrust I received a private key, a public key and an intermediate certificate all in PEM format. These are all the steps I've made so far:

```
    keytool -genkeypair -alias company -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 7360 -keystore cdn.keystore -keypass pass -storepass pass  
    keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -storepass pass -alias primaryca -keystore cdn.keystore -file public.pem  
    openssl pkcs12 -export -in public.pem -inkey private.pem -CAfile ca.pem -name company -out keystore.p12  
    keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass pass -destkeypass pass -destkeystore cdn.keystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
```

The third passage ask me to overwrite the company entry inserted in the first passage: if I say no, the browser doesn't recognized the GeoTrust certificate and it treats it like a normal self signed certificate. If I say yes, all seems to work properly but if I check my installation with [GeoTrust CryptoReport](https://cryptoreport.geotrust.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp) (or another site) it tells me it miss intermediate key and it's not trusted.

If I open the site with Chrome or Firefox I don't receive any security warning, but I'm concerned that the previous error could lead to incompatibilities with Microsoft ADFS (I use Spring Security SAML).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the simple steps for a correct installation in my case, [following this solution](http://www.fourproc.com/2010/06/23/create-a-ssl-keystore-for-a-tomcat-server-using-openssl-.html):

```
1. cat ca.pem /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt > allcacerts.pem
2. openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -in public.pem -inkey private.pem -out server.p12 -name server -CAfile allcacerts.pem -caname root
3. keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass YOURPASS -destkeypass YOURPASS -destkeystore my.keystore -srckeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass YOURPASS -alias YOURALIAS
```

The first passage is required to avoid openssl errors. In second passage you have to specify a passphrase which will be YOURPASS, also used for your keystore and in `standalone.xml`.